# Implement vertical mouse wheel event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing an application for smart TV, which seems they do not support default page scroll event on their remote control wheel event. my question is that how I can implement the page scroll event using jquery code. I have started with this peace of code:

```
$(".page").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollDown -= (delta * 30);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

but this code does not seem to work in the right way, and It seems that works for only works for vertical mouse events. how can I support both horizontal and vertical scrolls in one block of code?

Comment: What is `.scrollDown` supposed to be? There's no such property.

Comment: Hm, try to use offset
    `$(".page").offset().left + $(".page").outerWidth();`,
    `$(".page").offset().top;`

etc

Comment: It's not clear, how to get the offset change with respect to mouse wheel movement.

Comment: you can use this.scrollLeft for vertical scroll